# is there a reason why <script> has to have a separate closing tag?

Tags: html, theory

To start, I know that I have to have the `</script>` tag, and there are existing questions about that. The question isn't whether or not I need a closing tag. My question is: *why* was it designed this way?

The source of confusion for me comes from looking at the `<link />` element - it appears to have similar functionality (importing external text files and defining their type) but has the self-closing property (which we see in other but not all element types). I may be oversimplifying things, but I don't understand why one external reference element should use a style that is different from another similar (obviously not the same) external reference element.

It looks like this doesn't change in the HTML5 draft either. I just want to understand the reasoning behind it so I can have a better/deeper understanding of basic HTML and why it works the way it does.

Comment: well, i can use inline script-blocks `<script>{code}</script>` and that might be the reason for it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> why was it designed this way?

It must have an explicit end tag because you can have inline script:

```
<script>
    foo();
</script>
```

Having a forbidden end tag wouldn't work (since then you couldn't have content). Having an optional end tag would be more trouble then it is worth (since the element contains CDATA … that might actually make it impossible to have an optional end tag, I don't know that bit of SGML well enough to say).

It doesn't use `<link>` because it was a product of the browser wars and not something that was discussed in the W3C before being introduced.

> It looks like this doesn't change in the HTML5 draft either.

It wouldn't be backwards compatible.

Comment: +1 for backwards compatibility. Your other reasons are simply incidental.

Comment: What you're saying here makes sense, but then why would I not want to consider `<link />` default tag for importing JS files, and compartmentalize the use of `<script>` to in-line code?

Comment: Actually, it would make sense to be able to say `<script src="file.js" />`, because you simply cannot put content inside a `script` tag that also specifies `src`, so having to close it separately is kind of absurd.

Comment: That would require different rules for a tag being optional or not depending on which attributes the start tag had, which would be horrible (and not something that SGML made possible).